# AWS data pipeline: dump data to 3 s3 nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-data-pipeline

I have a use case wherein I want to take a data from DynamoDB and do some transformation on the data. After this I want to create 3 csv files (there will be 3 transformations on the same data) and dump them to 3 different s3 locations.
My architecture would be sort of following:
[image]

Is it possible to do so? I can't seem to find any documentation regarding it. If it's not possible using pipeline, are there any other services which could help me with my use case?

These dumps will be scheduled daily. My other consideration was using aws lamda. But according to my understanding, it's event based triggered rather time based scheduling, is that correct?

Comment: You can use CloudWatch rules to trigger Lambda functions on a schedule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks amith for your answer. I have been busy for quite some time now. I did some digging after you posted your answer. Turns out we can dump the data to different s3 locations using Hive activity as well.

This is how the data pipeline would like in that case.

[image]

But I believe writing multiple hive activities, when your input source is DynamoDB table, is not a good idea since hive doesn't load any data in memory. It does all the computations on the actual table which could deteriorate the performance of the table. Even documentation suggests to export the data incase you need to make multiple queries to same data. [Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/EMR_Interactive_Hive.html)

> Enter a Hive command that maps a table in the Hive application to the data in DynamoDB. This table acts as a reference to the data stored in Amazon DynamoDB; the data is not stored locally in Hive and any queries using this table run against the live data in DynamoDB, consuming the table’s read or write capacity every time a command is run. If you expect to run multiple Hive commands against the same dataset, consider exporting it first.

In my case I needed to perform different type of aggregations on the same data once a day. Since dynamoDB doesn't support aggregations, I turned to Data pipeline using Hive. In the end we ended up using AWS Aurora which is My-SQL based.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but not using HiveActivity instead EMRActivity. If you look into Data pipeline documentation for [HiveActivity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-hiveactivity.html), it clearly states its purpose and not suits your use case:

> > Runs a Hive query on an EMR cluster. HiveActivity makes it easier to set up an Amazon EMR activity and **automatically creates Hive tables based on input data** coming in from **either Amazon S3 or Amazon RDS**. All you need to specify is the HiveQL to run on the source data. AWS Data Pipeline automatically creates Hive tables with ${input1}, ${input2}, and so on, based on the input fields in the HiveActivity object.

Below is how your data pipeline should look like. There is also a inbuilt template `Export DynamoDB table to S3` in UI for AWS Data Pipeline which creates the basic structure for you, and then you can extend/customize to suit your requirements.

[image]

To your next question using **Lambda**, Of course lambda can be configured to have **event based triggering or schedule based triggering**, but I wouldn't recommend using `AWS Lambda` for any ETL operations as they are **time bound** & usual ETLs are longer than lambda time limits.

AWS has specific optimized feature offerings for ETLs, `AWS Data Pipeline` & `AWS Glue`, I would always recommend to choose between one of two. In case your ETL involves data sources not managed within AWS compute and storage services OR any speciality use case which can't be sufficed by above two options, then `AWS Batch` will be my next consideration.